# Create and update database with input from PageView.builder in flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have a PageView.builder that has a textFormfield and a title. The builder iterates through the elements of the list and once on the last one, there is a submit button that I would like to send the Key : Value pairs to firestore. when I use for each, it only creates the content of the last item of the list multiple times.

here is my create and update function:

```
        Future updateDatabase(String remarkText) async {
          return await databaseCollection.document().setData({
            questionItems[index].title : questionItems[index].remarkText 
          });
        }
```

and this is how I call it in my button

```
                  onPressed: () async { 
                    questionItems.forEach((question) async { 
                    await updateDatabase(remarkText);
                    });

                  },
```

How can I loop through them to send data for the previous items as well? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's iterating over all items, but updating always the same item in Firestore. The variable `index` should be changed in each iteration somehow. Otherwise each iteration will set value on the same `questionItems[index]`.

I hope it will help!

Comment: I thought this would work too. but when I make it questionItems[index] I get an error (forEach) isnt defined. I am really stuck on this.

Comment: I thought of this and I have a problem to understand what structure of documents/fields you are trying to create. Can you add some more about this?

Comment: I am creating Key : Value pairs to update to a Firestore collection. The Key is the title and the value is the remarktext. If the field doesnt exist on Firestore, it creates, if it exists, it sets the new data

Comment: But, if it should be a map why do you use index? Is it an array of maps?